# tab does not switch to edit / object mode

Tags: workflow, customization, keymap

On my main computer I press tab to switch between edit mode and object mode. But on my second computer (with the same blender version 3.01 installed) hitting tab just opens the radial menu where I can select one of the modes (edit, paint, sculpt and so on). I find it faster to use tab for switching instantly like it works on my main computer. How can I change the settings? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Set Object Mode` to switch between edit/object mode directly

`Object Mode Menu` to switch modes using pie menu

[image: Blender prefercenes]